# Specify an optional environment property in Apache Camel XML

Tags: apache-camel

I am using an environment variable in Apache Camel which is optional and in certain cases the value won't be there, but still I want my config to work, assuming the not found environment variable as blank.

```
camelContext id="inboud" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <!-- and then let Camel use those @Component scanned route builders -->
    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties"
        location="properties/app${env}.properties" ignoreMissingLocation="true" />

    <!-- Messages placed here will be raw data from force.com-->
    <template id="frceProducerTemplate" />
```

Here the ${env} I want to make as optional and if it's not present then the location must be taken as properties/app.properties.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for default values if an ENV variable is not there. You can read more about using property placeholders here: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

However you can likely add 2 locations, one with the ENV and another without the ENV. And then turn on `ignoreMissingLocation="true"` then if the ENV is not there Camel will ignore it.

Comment: thanks the hack looks good but dont I have to specify like`<propertyPlaceholder id="properties"
        location="properties/app.properties,properties/app${env?.}.properties" ignoreMissingLocation="true" />` as env will not be present in some cases .Also will the property file coming later in the order override the first

Comment: yeah something like that, give it a try and see

Comment: let me try to hack something out (will post an answer once I get it working ) .But I think apache camel must add support for the Elvis operator for defaults like SPEL does

Comment: `<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="properties/app.properties,properties/app${env}.properties" ignoreMissingLocation="true" />` solved it as per @claus-ibsen suggestion where if env exists the props are overridden else default props is used.

Comment: @ClausIbsen, I tried this but it didn't seem to work with IgnoreMissingLocation. It loads both locations and if one of them is missing it throws an exception saying the file was not found. Seems using blueprint has some limitation compared to the pure java propertiescomponent.